# EF6 get identity column value after SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I know this question has been asked like 100 times before because I've checked out most of them. None of them seem to work with EF6 though.

Simply, I want to use EF6 to write a record into a SQL Server database, and then recover the value of the Identity column after doing SaveChanges().

Here's my simple program:

```
        using (var ctx = new myEntities())
        {
            ctx.TinyUrl_Url.Add(new TinyUrl_Url()
            {
                UrlValue = tinyUrl
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The TinyUrl_Url table has 2 columns: UrlValue, and the Identity PK of UrlID. How can I get the value of UrlID after inserting the new row using EF6?

Thank you.

Comment: var addedUrl = ctx.TinyUrl_Url.Add(...); After SaveChanged the Id of object AddedUrl if filled with the Id that was given to the object that was inserted into the database

Answer (score 0):

```
int Id = ctx.UrlID;
```

Personally I do it this way-

```
context.Customers.Add(customer);
context.SaveChanges();//this generates the Id for customer
order.CustomerId = customer.Id;//finally I can set the Id
```

Should work after saving.

Comment: I must be missing something because in trying to translate your code into mine, I still get a compile error. Here's what I have, trying to use your idea:

            using (var ctx = new myEntities())
            {
                ctx.TinyUrl_Url.Add(new TinyUrl_Url()
                {
                    UrlValue = tinyUrl
                });
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                long theID = TinyUrl_Url.Id;   // no such property, Id

Can you please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: firstly create a new obj of TinyUrl and then add url to its property pass the object and then check @BarryDysert